Moengage React Native integration validation unsuccessful?
currently we try to implement Moegange as engangement tool for our app, we already follow the necessary steps here https://developers.moengage.com/hc/en-us/categories/4404199274900-React-Native-SDK
everythings works fine, we able to build the debug app just fine, but when we try to validation the integration using the built in tools, seems like it doesnt work, the intent url wont launch and validate the app
because moengange doesnt really print any useful console log, then i try to look up the device log using logcat, and the moengage log is indeed printed there, but i can't find anything really explain why i cant validate the integration
but theres a line that concern me, and might be an inkling why the integration doesnt work ?
11-25 14:50:55.833 11241 11296 V MoEngage: xxxxxxxxxx_DEBUG Core_ReportsHandler syncData() : response: ReportAddResponse(isSuccess=false, responseCode=1000, message=Account/SDK disabled.)
any help appreciated, thank you

It looks like there might be a miss in the integration step, please check that the correct workspace ID and datacenter are set during initialization.
If the issue persists, please reach out to the MoEngage support team via the MoEngage dashboard.

right, so let me answer my own question
theres miscommunication about the workspace id, it seems that the workspace on both environtment (release and test) have the same workspace id, BUT to use the test env, you can't manually add the _DEBUG behind the workspace id, it only applicable for API access for manual hit
so if you want to use the TEST env, you need to build the app in debug mode, if you build it in release mode, it'll use the MoEngage live env
